# Throwing exceptions from constructor - is it necessary subclass has to throw as well?

Tags: java

I am reading a topic of throwing exceptions from constructors. After a bit of studying same topic over stackflow. I have come to conclusion that we can throw exceptions from constructors. The issue occurs when we try to subclass the parent whose constructor throw an exception. For example, see the following code snippet below.

```
class  ParentConstructorException{
  public ParentConstructorException() throws IOException {

  }
}

public class TestConstructorException extends ParentConstructorException {
  public TestConstructorException() throws Exception{

  }
  //Causes compile time error if i don't throw exception
  public TestConstructorException(int x){

  }
}
```

I have provided a no-arg constructor in the child class that throws a broader exception.
When i overload the constructor, it says i didn't handle the checked exception. So it means
we cannot initiate the subclass without throwing the checked exception which is same or 
broader? Can someone explain please.
Ben

Comment: Do you have a genuine use case to throw an exception in a constructor? Although I'm sure there are exceptions - it may point to a design flaw anyway

Comment: Hi Colin, i am also curious to know, if there are any practical usages to throw exceptions from constructors. If you are aware please share.

Comment: As Jon Skeet said, there are some cases - opening files would be a good example. But otherwise, as far as _checked_ exceptions go, they should be few and far between in constructors. `RuntimeException`s on the other hand a perfectly fine (for cases where you get invalid input data to your constructor)

Comment: Thanks Colin, i got your point. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well each subclass will chain to a superclass constructor. In your case, that's happening implicitly - for example this:

```
public TestConstructorException(int x) {
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public TestConstructorException(int x) {
  super();
}
```

You can't catch any exception thrown by that superclass constructor within the subclass constructor as the chaining to the superclass constructor must be the very first thing in the constructor body - you can't even start a `try` block.

So, what would you *expect* your subclass constructor to do if the superclass constructor threw an exception?

Comment: Thanks @Jon i got the point. On practical basis, how useful it is to throw exceptions from constructors?

Comment: @benz: It depends on the situation. It's perfectly reasonable for something like `FileInputStream` or `FileOutputStream`... or for unchecked exceptions to be thrown for validation errors etc.

Comment: Ah i see. I seem to get your point now. Thanks a ton Jon for clarifying the doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to declare the same exception, or at least a broader one in your sub class constructor, because the super class constructor is invoked by the sub class constructor only, in process of object creation, with the help of `super()` call. Either you give it explicitly, or the compiler add it for you as the first statement in all your constructor.

So, if the parent class constructor throws an exception, it will thrown to the sub class constructor. But *you cannot* use a `try-catch` block surrounding the `super()` call to handle the exception, as the `super()` has to be the first statement in your constructor. That is why compiler marks it as compile time error, if it does not see that exception as declared to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

> When i overload the constructor, it says i didn't handle the checked
>   exception. So it means we cannot initiate the subclass without
>   throwing the checked exception which is same or broader?

You can't handle exceptions cause `super()` is called before your subclass is executed.

```
public TestConstructorException(int x){
  super(); // this throws IOException , and it's a checkedException so this won't compile
}
```

What about if you try with `try-catch`?

**This won't compile.Cause you can't do this. *super()* is called in first statement**

```
public TestConstructorException(int x){
 try{ 
 super(); // this throws IOException
}catch(IOException e){
 //do something
}
```

So you have to throw too

```
 public TestConstructorException(int x) throws IOException{

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Super class constructor (super())` declares its exception, so it leaves up to the caller, i.e, `subclass constructor`. Either subclass constructor declares (by throws) or surrounds `super()` by `try-catch`.

Compiler prompts as "add exception to the method signature" if it is not added to method signature.

if `super()` is called inside `try-catch`, Compiler complains as "Call to 'super()' must be first statement in constructor body". This second option is not the solution for unhandled exception.